# Creating a Global user authentication system using MVC4 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am starting a ASP.NET project soon that will require user authentication to access certain parts of the site.  There will be multiple sites requiring this authentication system including desktop applications.

I was wondering, is there a way to essentially create a global authentication system using the MVC4 Web API? I don't mean authenticate the user to access the API, but to allow users to retrieve an authentication token to access the site via the web-api.

Sorry if this seems a bit confusing, I'm still trying to figure out the best method to use.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing service like [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)?

Comment: You may want to consider creating or using an existing openid platform.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Thinktecture. They have created a token provider (with a client to show how to use it). I think this is what you're looking for.

http://thinktecture.github.com/